# Trying to convert the date which is in character format

Tags: r, date, as.date

My dataset has 90,000 odd records. date format is as below:

```
timestamp
2018-01-27T09:01:49Z
2018-01-27T00:04:08Z
2018-01-27T09:04:22Z
2018-01-27T09:04:28Z
2018-01-27T00:07:38Z
```

I tried

```
as.Date(recfive$timestamp, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I am getting all NA

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date separators in your strings are "-" and not "/"

Try `as.Date(recfive$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d")`

or `as.POSIXct(recfive$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` if you want a datetime object

Comment: Thank you. If I run as.POSIXct I got datetime object, but I can see that few obs are getting omitted. how do I avoid that and include them in my actual dataset

Comment: Note that `as.POSIXct()` will ignore the timezone indicator `Z` (*Zulu* = *UTC*) on input and will use the local timezone by default. So the resulting POSIXct objects will be different from the given datetime strings (unless your local timezone is set to *UTC*).

Answer (score 0):

#### Coercing ISO 8601 standard timestamps to class Date

The timestamps are already in  [ISO 8601 standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which is unambiguous. Therefore, *no* format specification is required when converting *to class Date*:

```
as.Date(recfive$timestamp)
#> [1] "2018-01-27" "2018-01-27" "2018-01-27" "2018-01-27" "2018-01-27"
```

#### Coercing ISO 8601 standard timestamps to class POSIXct (datetime)

When coercing to a datetime object (class `POSIXct`), the timezone has to be specified. Although, the timezone is already indicated in the input data by the trailing letter `Z` (as *Zulu* = *UTC*) this is ignored on input, unfortunately.

In my current locale, the local timezone is used which creates a POSIXct object where the timestamps denote different instances in time than specified (during Winter, CET is one hour ahead of UTC).

```
as.POSIXct(recfive$timestamp)
#> [1] "2018-01-27 CET" "2018-01-27 CET" "2018-01-27 CET" "2018-01-27 CET" "2018-01-27 CET"
```

So, the timezone has to be specified explicitely:

```
as.POSIXct(recfive$timestamp, tz = "UTC")
#> [1] "2018-01-27 UTC" "2018-01-27 UTC" "2018-01-27 UTC" "2018-01-27 UTC" "2018-01-27 UTC"
```

Note that `as.POSIXct()` has returned a truncated datetime denoting the start of the day.

To get the full datetimes as specified, `as.POSIXct()` can be called with a format specification:

```
as.POSIXct(recfive$timestamp, format = "%FT%TZ", tz = "UTC")
#> [1] "2018-01-27 09:01:49 UTC" "2018-01-27 00:04:08 UTC" "2018-01-27 09:04:22 UTC"
#> [4] "2018-01-27 09:04:28 UTC" "2018-01-27 00:07:38 UTC"
```

Alternatively, there is a number of packages which have specialized in simplified or fast coersion of datetime strings to class POSIXct which all return the same result:

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(recfive$timestamp)

anytime::anytime(recfive$timestamp, asUTC = TRUE)
anytime::utctime(recfive$timestamp, tz = "UTC")

fasttime::fastPOSIXct(recfive$timestamp, tz = "UTC")
```

#### Data

```
recfive <- data.table::fread(
"timestamp
2018-01-27T09:01:49Z
2018-01-27T00:04:08Z
2018-01-27T09:04:22Z
2018-01-27T09:04:28Z
2018-01-27T00:07:38Z")
```